# How is the file from OneToOne Model's FileField accessed, read in views.py and passed to template?

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, filefield

I am developing a simple Data Visualization App, where a user can register, login upload a file and visualize its content.

I am using default `User` model, and a `Detail` Model having OneToOne relation with `User` Model. The `Detail` has 3 fields, which are:

```
OneToOne(User)
FileField()
TextField()
```

Now, I want to access the file that is saved in `FileField, in` views.py`and read it's content, then visualize it using Python's`NumPy`and`Matplotlib`, then finally show visualization results on the frontend.

I need a guidance that how should I start and approach this task? Basically, I need deep guidance in how to access and read the file in `views.py`?

My **`models.py`** is:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="CSV File", upload_to='csv_files/')
    file_desc = models.TextField("CSV File Description")

    def __str__(self):
        return ("{} ({} {})".format(self.user.email, self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name))
```

and in **`views.py`**, I am approaching it this way:

```
class VisualizeAPI(View):
    template_name = 'accounts/visualize.html'

    def get(self, request):
        msg = {'message': "Please login to view this page."}
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            detail, _ = Detail.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            context = {'detail': detail}

            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        return render(request, self.template_name, msg)
```

and in `template`, I am approaching it this way:

```
<body>
    <h1>Visualized Details</h1>
 
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ detail }}
    {% else %}
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

But it is not printing the content of the file on the frontend.
I will be glad for proper approach and guidance provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the CSV file in your view and then pass it to your template.

```
import csv
from io import StringIO


class VisualizeAPI(View):
    template_name = "accounts/visualize.html"

    def get(self, request):
        msg = {"message": "Please login to view this page."}

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            detail, _ = Detail.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            if detail.file:
                # Read file from detail object
                file = detail.file.read().decode("utf-8")
                # Parse file as csv
                csv_data = csv.reader(StringIO(file), delimiter=",")
            else:
                csv_data = None
            context = {
                "detail": detail,
                "csv_data": csv_data,
            }

            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        return render(request, self.template_name, msg)
```

Then you can print each row of your csv file in your template.

```
<body>
  <h1>Visualized Details</h1>

  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {{ detail }}
  {% for row in csv_data %}
    {{ row }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
  <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
</body>
```